# Controlling(play/pause) VLC from separate application

Tags: windows, visual-c++, vlc, video-player

I want to control(play/pause) VLC mediaplayer from my own application. How can I achieve that?
Please note: I'm developing for windows laptop using VC++ and application as well as videos are offline(i.e. internet isn't used at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article on Code Project may be of use to you.

*VLCWrapper - A Little C++-wrapper Around libvlc*
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38952/VLCWrapper-A-Little-C-wrapper-Around-libvlc

Or you could just use libvlc directly. I found a *LibVLC Tutorial* at https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/.

I hope this helps.